# get model list from a json array kotlin

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

In my code I am trying to get Income type object list from a json file

```
   val fileJson = File(
        Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS),
        "Income.json")
    val strFileJson: String? = fileJson.readText()
    val PreviousJsonObj: JSONObject = JSONObject(strFileJson)
    val array: JSONArray = PreviousJsonObj.getJSONArray("Incomes")
    val typeToken = object : TypeToken<List<Income>>() {}.type
    IncomeArry = Gson().fromJson<List<Income>>(strFileJson, typeToken)
```

But I am getting
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

The value returned in strFileJson is "Incomes":[{"date":"abc","src": "cfgb","amt": 7890},
{"date":"yui", "src":"tyhv","amt" :6789}]

Tried running with multiple imple,mentations of gson and multiple class architectures

Answer (score 0):

The fragment of JSON you show:

```
"Incomes":[{"date":"abc","src": "cfgb","amt": 7890}, {"date":"yui", "src":"tyhv","amt" :6789}]
```

is malformed, did you mis-paste?  It needs to be enclosed in curly braces:

```
{"Incomes":[{"date":"abc","src": "cfgb","amt": 7890}, {"date":"yui", "src":"tyhv","amt" :6789}]}
```

but this will not solve your problem because both will give the error you describe.  You are trying to deserialize an **array** so you need to either

1. Change the JSON to be

```
[{"date":"abc","src": "cfgb","amt": 7890}, {"date":"yui", "src":"tyhv","amt" :6789}]
```

2. Or create a wrapper object, something like

```
data class Incomes(
 val Incomes : List<Income>
)
```

and deserialize in to that.